# Draw clockwise filled in circle

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a cooldown visual for my game when actions are used. I want the button that I have that is the action to be filled with a grayish semi-transparent color that "unwinds" clockwise (if that makes sense). Games like World of Warcraft do this where the time it takes for the cooldown is the time the angle of the unwinding takes. You can see an example here. In this picture the cooldown is more than 1/2 way finished.

http://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=101705&stc=1&d=1372575930

I'm playing around with arc drawing but this doesn't give me what I'm after.

```
if (globalCD)
{
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(125, 255, 0, 0), 10);
    //e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, 0), new Point(10, 10));

    e.Graphics.DrawArc(p, new Rectangle(0, 0, 64, 64), 270, 270);
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the `Graphics` class has a `FillX` method for each `DrawX` method. In this case the result is sufficiently different that the names actually change a bit, but you likely want the `FillPie` method.

```
if (globalCD)
{
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(125, 255, 0, 0), 10);
    //e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, 0), new Point(10, 10));

    e.Graphics.FillPie(p, new Rectangle(0, 0, 64, 64), 270, 270);
}
```